python pyperclip does not copy to clipboard after upgrade to 24.04
I recently upgraded to Ubuntu version 24.04, and python scripts using the pyperclip module no longer copy to the clipboard. The terminal shows no error message.

Please avoid making up your own version numbers. I fixed yours.
